# Unable to Display a Variable on a Label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using the popular tkinter approach where the original author tried an "pseudo MVC" pattern. Here is the code:

```
class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for f in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = f(container, self)
            self.frames[f] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        def inputs():
            r=rq.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
            page2 = self.controller.get_page(PageTwo)
            page2.resp.set(r.json()['name'])
            self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo)

        b = tk.Button(station_frame, text="Submit",command=inputs)
        b.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=5, padx=5)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.resp = tk.StringVar()
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=self.resp.get())
        lbl.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
```

while doing this my `lbl` comes empty and when i set `text=self.resp` it print `PY_VAR0`.
Now Here is the part which confuses me. when I change my `lbl` (Label) with a Button and calls a functions which just prints `self.resp.get()` it prints the value. Here is the code:

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.resp = tk.StringVar()
        def show():
            print(self.resp.get())

        btm = tk.Button(self, text='call', command=show)
        btm.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
```

I want to show the resp value on a `Label` on my PageTwo.

Comment: A Label's `text=` option is a one-time action - it's not going to magically reevaluate the value passed to that option whenever it changes.  You want `textvariable=` instead - that accepts Tk Vars directly, and creates a listener that updates the Label whenever that Var changes.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing that out @jasonharper

Comment: `lbl["text"] = "new text"`

Comment: it seems your Label is created when `self.resp` is still empty but you press `Button` when `self.resp` already have some value. `Label` will not wait for value in `self.resp` so you have to update text manually when you change value in `self.resp` - `lbl["text"] = self.resp.get()`. OR you have to use `textvariable=self.resp` to do it automatically.

Comment: I haven't tried this way. I will try that sure. @furas